# How to get scrape all the td and tr data from NFL schedule

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping data from the espn.com for the upcoming NFL schedule. However, I am only able to get the first line  of table and the not the rest of the tables. I believe it is because of structure of the html and the each date has a different 'td'. I can get Thursday's game data but, not the rest

****Thursday, September 5****
MATCHUP     TIME  (ET)  NAT TV  TICKETS LOCATION
    Green Bay
    Chicago
8:20 PM NBC Tickets as low as $290  Soldier Field, Chicago
**Sunday, September 8**
MATCHUP     TIME  (ET)  NAT TV  TICKETS LOCATION
    Tennessee
    Cleveland
1:00 PM CBS Tickets as low as $121  FirstEnergy Stadium, Cleveland

Cincinnati
Seattle
4:05 PM CBS Tickets as low as $147  CenturyLink Field, Seattle
    New York
    Dallas
4:25 PM FOX Tickets as low as $50   AT&T Stadium, Arlington 
    Foxboro 
**Monday, September 9**
MATCHUP     TIME  (ET)  NAT TV  TICKETS LOCATION
    Houston 
    New Orleans
7:10 PM ESPN    Tickets as low as $112  Mercedes-Benz Superdome, New Orleans
    Denver
    Oakland
10:20 PM    ESPN    Tickets as low as $72   Oakland Coliseum, Oakland

I have use beautifulsoup and was easily about to get the data, but parsing the data has been a challenged.

I have tried to just continuing using a for loop, but I can a stopiteration traceback. After reading the previous article about the traceback I realize that I need to try a different solution to the problem.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import pandas as pd


main_url = ['http://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule'][1]

response = requests.get(main_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('table')
rows = table.find_all('tr')
rows = iter(rows)

df = [td.text for td in next(rows).find_all('td') if td.text]
df2 = [td.text for td in next(rows).find_all('td') if td.text]


[1]: https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem lies in this line :

```
table = soup.find('table')
```

The thing is, the  above mentioned page consists of 3 `table` elements that have the `class = "schedule"` attribute. However in your code, you used the `find()` function only, instead of `find_all()`. That's the major reason that you ended up with only the contents of the first table. So, I believe that if just handle that part correctly then you'll be good to go. Now, I'm not much familiar with the set notation used to fill up the lists, hence the code contains the good old `for` loop style.

```
#List to store the rows 
df = []
#Collect all the tables
tables = soup.find_all('table', class_ = "schedule")
for table in tables:
    rows = soup.find_all('tr')
    #rows = iter(rows)
    row_item = []
    for row in rows:
        #Collect all 'td' elements from the 'row' & append them to a list 'row_item'
        data_items = row.find_all('td')
        for data_item in data_items: 
            row_item.append(data_item.text)
        #Append the list to the 'df'
        df.append(row_item)
        row_item = []

print(df)
```

Comment: thanks for the response, I tried the code, but the df did not  show any data. I tried within the loop and outside the loop and I received a traceback said it is not defined.

Comment: Just declare `df` as an empty list prior to the line in which `tables`  is  declared. Python will then be able to consider the `df` variable as a list and then it'll allow the usage of it in the further lines.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you, the great thing is that it can be easily manipulated through pandas later on in the project. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to pull `<table>` tags, you can use Pandas `.read_html()` to do that. It'll return a list of dataframes. In this case, you can append them all together into 1 table:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule'

tables = pd.read_html(url)

df = pd.DataFrame()
for table in tables:
    df = df.append(table)
```